# Study of a PDE (with separation of variables) with first and second order derivative of the spatial part.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm in trouble with this problem

$$\begin{cases}
u_{t}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)-2u_{x}(x,t)=0\qquad \mathrm {for}\;(x,t)\in(0,\ell)\times\mathbb R^{+} \\ 
u(x,0)=2e^{-x}\sin(\frac{3\pi x}{\ell})\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\; \mathrm{for}\;x \in (0,\ell) \\ 
u(0,t)=u(\ell,t)=0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\mathrm{for} \;t\in\mathbb{R^{+}}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\ell \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$.

It'd a PDE whit boundary and initial conditions, but I see it a little bit strange for my knowledge. It has both first and second derivatives for spatial ($x$) part and a first order derivative for the temporal part.
I start the study as always:

$$U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$
$$T'X=TX''+2TX'$$
$$\frac{T'}{T}(t)=\frac{X''+2X'}{X}(x)$$
$$\frac{T'}{T}=\frac{X''+2X'}{X}=\lambda$$
for some constant $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to solve, considering the boundary conditions:
$$\begin{cases}
X''(x)+2X'(x)=\lambda X\\
X(0)=X(\ell)=0
\end{cases}
$$
and, for the temporal part:
$$T(t)=\lambda T(t)$$
with $t>0$.

Ok, but now I'm stucked. I don't know how to treat the spatial component in order to select some value of $\lambda$ to see what happens putting the boundary conditions to find the costants. Could someone give me a hint to let me start and solve the problem? I really want to learn this stuff! Thank you!.

Edit:

My progress (My idea)

$$X(x)=c_{1}e^{-(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}+1)x}+c_{2}e^{(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}-1)x}$$

I rewrite as
$$X(x)=c_{1}e^{-(\sqrt{\lambda + 1})x}e^{x}+c_{2}e^{(\sqrt{\lambda + 1})x}e^{-x}$$

Now I suppose $\lambda+1=\alpha^{2}<0$ in order to have the solution like as:

$$X(x)=a\cos(\alpha x)+b\sin(\alpha x)$$
Using the boundary conditions:
$$X(0)=a=0$$
$$X(\ell)=b\sin(\alpha\ell)=0$$
So 
$$\alpha=\frac{n \pi}{l}$$
I have finally found $\lambda$ and a value for $c_{1}=0$ and $c_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\neq0.$

$$\lambda=-\alpha^{2}-1$$
Note the minus sign for $\alpha^{2}$: I placed it because of the hypothesis for $a^{2}<0$.
So
$$U(x,t)=c_{2}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{\ell}x)e^{-x}e^{-(1+\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{\ell ^{2}})t}$$

Including the temporal part as $T'(t)=c_{n}e^{-(\alpha^{2}+1)t}$.

Comment: It is just an ODE (maybe not so easy to solve). Wolfram gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B2y%27-a*y%3D0).

Comment: To solve these types of ODE's, you try out $e^{rt}$. Then you get a quadratic equation and solve for $r$. [Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SecondOrderConcepts.aspx) is more on how to solve these things (also go to next section).

Comment: Ok, here we are. Assuming I have solved the ODE. I have the following solution: $$X(x)=c_{1}e^{-(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}+1)x}+c_{2}e^{(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}-1)x}$$
Now it seems that I can rewrite as:
$$X(x)=c_{1}\sinh((\sqrt{\lambda + 1}+1)x)+ c_{2}\cosh((\sqrt{\lambda + 1}+1)x)$$
Which, applying the boundary conditions I have founded, gives me the trial solutions $c_{1}=0 \qquad c_{2}=0$. Do you have any idea about how I can treat this situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your second formula is not consistent with the first one (some signs are wrong). Also please add all the new results to the question, instead of comments. As for boundary conditions, please check again

Comment: With a little bit of fantasy I comed with this idea:
$$X(x)=c_{1}e^{-(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}+1)x}+c_{2}e^{(\sqrt{\lambda + 1}-1)x}$$

I rewrite as
$$X(x)=c_{1}e^{-(\sqrt{\lambda + 1})x}e^{x}+c_{2}e^{(\sqrt{\lambda + 1})x}e^{-x}$$

Now I suppose $\lambda+1=\alpha^{2}<0$ in order to have the solution like as:

$$X(x)=a\cos(\alpha x)+b\sin(\alpha x)$$
Using the boundary conditions:
$$X(0)=a=0$$
$$X(\ell)=b\sin(\alpha\ell)=0$$

Comment: So 
$$\alpha=\frac{n \pi}{l}$$
I have finally found $\lambda$ and a value for $c_{1}=0$ and $c_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\neq0.$

$$\lambda=-\alpha^{2}-1$$
Note the minus sign for $\alpha^{2}$: I placed it because of the hypothesis for $a^{2}<0$.
So
$$U(x,t)=c_{2}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{\ell}x)e^{-x}e^{-(1+\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{\ell ^{2}})}$$

Is it pure use of imagiantion or my idea is a good one? Thank you very much.